# Dependence of variables in Mathematica 7.0

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

How can i get from equation one variable as a function of other variables? For example we have A*x^2 + R1*V*x + R2*v + z = 0; and i must get result V(R1,R2) = -(A*x^2 + z)/ (R1*x+R2). This is ofcourse simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate `Solve` and `Reduce`.  This is, of course, a simple answer but should get you started.